# Change the type of an object in python?

Tags: python, types, casting

I would like to assign a type to an object via a function, something like:

```
def set_type(obj,dest_type):
    [change the object to the dest_type here]
    return obj
```

I need to do this because I read parameters from a file as strings and they are afterwards interpreted as integers, floats and booleans.
Sure, I could write something like

```
if dest_type=='bool':
    bool(obj)
```

but is there no better way to do this? like directly giving the type to the function?

Thanks!

Comment: `type(dest_type)(obj)` ?

Comment: The sounds like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why don't you use a serialization format that understands theses types? JSON or pickle would both work here.

Comment: You can do dest_type(obj) and passing bool, int etc to your function

Comment: @Mathieu that would be something like type(bool)('True') but that doesn't seem to do what I want

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga I wanted to use a text file so other people can easily edit it to choose their parameters

Comment: @MaxS You want to convert the object obj to the type dest_type. Correct? Well, assuming the dest_type initialization takes as parameter the object, it does the conversion.

Comment: @Mathieu I wanted to give it the type for dest_type. I think it works like in the answer below. But Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just pass the type of the new object.
For instance,

```
>>> def convert(v,t):
...     return t(v)


>>> a = "test"
>>> b = convert(a,list)
>>> b
['t', 'e', 's', 't']
>>> b = convert(a,bool)
>>> b
True
>>> b = convert(b,int)
>>> b
1
>>> b = convert(b,float)
>>> b
1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can expect a function as `dest_type`, e.g. the function `bool()`. In that case your method will become:

```
def set_type(obj, dest_type):
    return dest_type(obj)
```

Example

```
obj = 1
set_type(obj, bool) # Yields True
```